# jQuery on click with radio button should show the particular div

Tags: jquery, html

In html markup is something like this

```
<div id="sales-menu-wrp">
    <div class="radio-buttons-wrap">
      <input type="radio" id="create_sales" name="toggler"/>Create Sales 
      <input type="radio" id="manage-sales" name="toggler" checked="checked" /> Manage Sales
    </div><!--.radio-buttons-wrap-->
  <div id="sales-details-form"  style="display:none;" >
    <div class="sales-product-details-wrap">
      <table id="sales-details-heading">
        <tr>
          <th>Products</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Discount Type</th>
          <th>Discount Price</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="sales-product-details">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table><!--#sales-product-detail-->

    </div><!--.sales-product-details-wrap-->
    </div><!--#sales-details-form-->
    <div id="sales-details-managment" style="" >
      <div class="managment-header">
        <ul>
          <li>Store Name</li>
          <li>Store Location</li>
          <li>Store Code</li>
          <li>Products</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <table class="sales-total-desc">
        <tr>
          <td>store test</td>
          <td>store test</td>
          <td>store test</td>
          <td>store test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>         
    </div><!--#sales-details-managment-->
  </div><!--#sales-menu-wrap-->
```

Here you can see that I have two `radio buttons`. One is for `Create Sales` means when one will click that button it will show the `create sales form` and other one is for `Sales Managment` which will on click show the `managment section`. So in final I want that when someone will go to the page it will show the `sales managment section` and the sales create form will be hidden by default.
So for all that I just used jQuery code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input:radio").click(function(){
    $('#sales-details-form').toggle(); 
    $('#sales-details-managment').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

It's working here but when someone will refresh the page then the Sales create button works with managment div and managment radio button on click shows the sales create form. So can someone kindly tell me how to fix this issue so that when some will click sales managment radio button then it should only show the managment section and someone will click create sales then it will show the sales create form. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: This code is working fine i checked on jsfiddle. where is the buttons??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test which of the radio buttons was clicked and `.hide()` or `.show()` accordingly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('input[name="toggler"]').click(function () {
        if (this.id === "create_sales") {
            $('#sales-details-form').show();
            $('#sales-details-managment').hide();
        } else {
            $('#sales-details-form').hide();
            $('#sales-details-managment').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5rH/

Or, for more compact code you can take advantage of the fact that [`.toggle()` optionally accepts a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) indicating whether to show or hide:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('input[name="toggler"]').click(function () {
        var isCreate = (this.id === "create_sales");
        $('#sales-details-form').toggle(isCreate);
        $('#sales-details-managment').toggle(!isCreate);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5rH/1/

Comment: You should also use `change` instead of `click`, not everyone uses the mouse click to interact with a form.

Comment: @David - Selecting radio buttons via the keyboard does generate click events (you can see that for yourself in my demo), but doesn't necessarily generate change events until the control loses focus. So I believe click is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Use '**Change**' instead of '**Click**'

// set **display none** on `sales-details-managment` instead of  '`sales-details-form`'

```
<div id="sales-details-managment" style="display:none;" >
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#manage-sales").trigger('click');
    $("input:radio").change(function () {
        $('#sales-details-form, #sales-details-managment').toggle();
    });
  });
```